# Apk is rejected from Samsung Apps

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I've tried publish my apk to [Samsung Apps](http://www.samsungapps.com). It was rejected with description

> Failure Details: Your application package has failed the integrity
>   test. We run integrity test to prove the integrity of resources when
>   building the Application package, the hash values of the resource are
>   saved and the values are compared with the extracted hash values from
>   the original resource to verify the integrity of the resource at the
>   time of building. File exists, but hash value does not exist. -
>   assets/49-Posterior sacrococcygeal ligament superficial and deep layers.mp3

Any ideas how can I fix it?

**UPDATE :**

I’ve already tried:

1. verify apk  with “jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs"
2. zipalign
3. zip -T

And no any issues. I have uploaded the same build to google market and amazon and it works!

Comment: That is a very strange explanation. You might try the Samsung forums on their developer site, if you have not done so already. Is there anything unusual about this file in your app?

Comment: Good tip. I've check, but not post it there yet. Nothing special about this file. I've published my app successful to Play Store.

Comment: Don't have something like "Resolution Center"..so that you could politely ask to elaborate?

Comment: @SajalDutta as I understand they suggest use their forum for support. I've just post my question there.

Comment: Please update us with your findings.

Comment: Just a wild guess,but have you tried renaming said asset file so it does not contain spaces?

Comment: @caspase I believe something wrong with file name, but it's hard to say what exactly. I have about 2000 sound files in my app. I've tried to delete this file and problem appears on another one. So now I'm working on renaming my content to more simple names.

Comment: I second the guess about spaces. Web servers don't like spaces in file names.

Comment: It's not the spaces, it's the length of the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Samsung integrity test has some issues with complicated content names (special characters, couple spaces in a row, etc) because same content was fine for Google Play and Amazon Store.

Samsung support wasn't great as well. Every time I've asked anything they've just suggest rebuild and try publish app again.

So in my case quick solution was to rename all content to his hash value like this `0009220d9375b63041e22997fd6f52c5.mp3`. That wasn't great, but it works.